# how to call alt + f4 key in angularjs onclick of button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to close the current tab on click of button. How to can I manually call Alt+F4 in angularjs

```js
$scope.cancel = function (event) {
    var keycode = event.keycode;
};
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" ng-click="cancel($event);">OK</button>
```

inside this cancel funtion I want to call Alt key and F4 key.

- ) Whenever I will click OK button I need to close the current tab.

`window.close()`, `$window.close()` nothing is working. SO i want to go in this way. please anyone help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 6):

> How to can I manually call Alt+F4 in angularjs

You can't.

> window.close(), $window.close() nothing is working.

JavaScript is not allowed to close a tab / window that wasn't opened with JavaScript in the first place.

For more information, see

- [MDN Web API Reference - window.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)